# Can someone explain about the Time-outs and validation of Azure AD Application access and refresh_token(s)?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

1. Can we use the same access token to request another app resource or validate Token. What happens after 3599 seconds to an access_token? can we still use it?
2. How many times we can use the same refresh token? (Is there any way to restrict to one time if possible)
3. How to check if the existing access_token and refresh_token were valid ones or not?

Please help.

PAVANSAI C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Can we use the same access token to request another app resource or validate Token. What happens after 3599 seconds to an access_token?
>      can we still use it?

When you acquire an access token, it is only meant to be used against certain resources (you specify them when you request a token). You can't use that token for any other resources. Generally an access token is valid for an hour (3600 seconds) but that's configurable at Azure AD level. Once this time period expires, you can't use that token anymore as using it will throw an error.

> 2. How many times we can use the same refresh token? (Is there any way to restrict to one time if possible)

Similar to access token, there's also an absolute expiration for refresh token (it is usually 14 days). When you use a refresh token to get a new access token, you also get a new refresh token. You should be using the new refresh token instead of an old one.

> 3. How to check if the existing access_token and refresh_token were valid ones or not?

A [successful response](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/azuread-dev/v1-protocols-oauth-code#successful-response-1) to an access token request will include the number of seconds the returned access token is valid for (`expires_in`), as well as the time at which the access token will expire (`expires_on`). Use these to keep track of whether the access token is still valid or not.

Note: You should consider using client libraries such as [MSAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-overview), which will do this automatically. Your code only needs to ask for a new token token, and the library will take care of figuring out if the last token received is still valid, or if a new one is needed.

Another possibly way to test it is try to use the access_token/refresh_token in an operation and catch the exception. Try to parse the exception to figure out what's wrong with the token. For example, if an access token has expired and you use it you will get an error telling you exactly that. That would be an indication for you to get a new access token using the refresh token. (This approach relies on the resource provider (i.e. the API) to return a message that clearly indicates that the token is expired, which is not always the case.)

Comment: I added some details on #3 for how to determine (from the token response) whether how long the access token is valid for.

Comment: @PhilippeSignoret Thanks for the edit. Much appreciated. I also thought of using the `expires_in` and `expires_on` but didn't include them as now you would have to take into account the machine's date/time + we will also need to accommodate clock skewness factor.

Comment: Hi @PhilippeSignoret, Can I get a REST API URL or JWT type validation of access token to validate the access tokens. What will be required to verify the signature? is it x5c? I tried the same.. still it's not working.. Please help me in verifying/ validating the access tokens.

Comment: You would only be looking at and validating an access token if your app is an API, and has been provided the access token by a client app (e.g. in an API call). Documentation for Azure AD access tokens: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens